# Is my claim correct, that there is a logical error in the solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, solution-verification

$\qquad \qquad \qquad$ [image]

I would like to know if my opinion about this solution is correct.

The solutions $x = 0$ and $x = -\frac 43$ are correct **if and only if** (iff)  such that $b=- \frac x2 \Longrightarrow \sqrt{x^2+x}=- \frac x2$  holds. Because, the variables $"a"$ and $"b"$ are dependent. They are not independent variables. So, the solution must be **if and only if**

$$\begin{cases} \displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+1}=\dfrac{2-x}{2} \\ \sqrt{x^2+x}=- \dfrac x2 \end{cases}$$

> Is my claim correct?

And here are my attempts:

> $$\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+x}=1-x \\ \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+x}\right) \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)=(1-x)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x}\right) \\ 1-x=(1-x)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x}\right) \\ \sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+x}=1, x\neq 1 \\ 2\sqrt{x^2+x}=-x \Longrightarrow x_1=0, x_2=- \frac 43 \\ 2\sqrt{x^2+1}=2-x \Longrightarrow x_1=0, x_2=-\frac 43  $$

Comment: The solution tells you, that if the original equation is true, then $x$ must be $x=\frac{-4}{3}$ or $x=0$. This is deduced by solving the system of two linear equations involving $a$ and $b$. They decide to eliminate $b$ and solve for $a$, but as they got the value of $a$, they implicitly got the value of $b$ as well (because, as you said, $a$ and $b$ are dependent on each other). It is sufficient to check if the original equation holds indeed for the two results, you don't have to solve the linear system for $b$ separately. If the results statisfy the original equation, you have an iff.

Comment: @Mr.Fox It is equivalent logic to solve second equation= check if the original equation holds

Comment: Yes, your method is right as well. My point is, if you got $x_{1}=\frac{−4}{3}$ and $x_{2}=0$ one way, you don't have to solve the other way as well, you only need to check if substituting the value of $x_{1}$ and then $x_{2}$ into the original equation gives you equal values on the left side and right side both times. The idea is that if you solve using your method or the original method, you get the set of possible solutions, and by checking if they are correct indeed, you get the set of all true solutions.

Comment: @Mr.Fox I understand you, control is required if the second equation is not solved. But in general, the method is incomplete. This called in mathematics necessary and sufficient conditions. Solving sistem of equation is necessarry and sufficient. But, solving one of them is necessarry but not sufficient.

Comment: There's also another gap: getting from $a+b=1-x$, $(a+b)(a-b)=1-x$ to $a-b=1$ you need to assume or prove $a+b\ne 0$.  It does turn out that's indeed the case, since the only way to have $a+b=0$, $a\ge 0$, $b\ge 0$ is if $a=b=0$ but then $x^2+x=x^2+1=0$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  But, is there any problem in my attempts?